# Print out dictionary by (specific) key

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, printing, key

I'm new to python and I have several dictionaries (all with pretty much the same keys) and I want to show a certain key first when I print it out. 
I know dicts can't be sorted and that's not what I want to do, I just want to print them according to a specific key order.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Employees:
    def __init__(self, name, job, pay, age=None):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.pay = pay
        self.age = age

    def gatherAttrs(self):
        attrs = []
        for key in self.__dict__:
            attrs.append('%s = %s' % (key, getattr(self,key)))
        return ', '.join(attrs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.gatherattrs())


sarah = Employees("Sarah Hopkins", "nurse", 60000, 30)
bob = Employees("Bob Smith", "doctor", 90000)

print sarah
print bob

output:
Employees: job = nurse, pay = 60000, age = 30, name = Sarah Hopkins
Employees: job = doctor, pay = 90000, age = None, name = Bob Smith
```

What I wanted was this:

```
Employees: name = Sarah Hopkins, job = nurse, pay = 60000, age = 30
```

I would like for the key 'name' (which exists in all dicts -that were converted to a list-) to be the first key-value pair to appear.

I don't know if in order to achieve this I need to convert the dicts to lists and then use the index (even though this might create problems later if I add new attributes), or if I should keep them as dicts and do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have classes with fixed attributes, the easiest solution is to iterate explicitly:

```
class Employees:
  def gatherAttrs(self):
    attrs = []
    for key in ["name", "job", "pay", "age"]:
        attrs.append('%s = %s' % (key, getattr(self,key)))
    return ', '.join(attrs)
```

Alternatively, you can iterate explicitly over *some* attributes only.

```
class Employees:
  _iter_attr__prio = ["name"]
  def gatherAttrs(self):
    attrs = []
    for key in self._iter_attr__prio + [key for key in self.__dict__ if key not in self._iter_attr__prio]:
        attrs.append('%s = %s' % (key, getattr(self,key)))
    return ', '.join(attrs)
```

Finally, you can try sorting:

```
class Employees:
  _iter_attr__prio = ["name"]
  def gatherAttrs(self):
    attrs = []
    for key in sorted(self.__dict__, key=lambda key: self. _iter_attr__prio.index(key) if key in self. _iter_attr__prio else 0, reverse=True):
        attrs.append('%s = %s' % (key, getattr(self,key)))
    return ', '.join(attrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). It pretty much acts like a regular `dict`, but it remembers the order items were entered.